# How to collapse a primesfaces datatable with a button or a command button?

Tags: primefaces, datatable, commandbutton

I want to show or hide a primefaces datatables by clicking on their command button, I have a java bean and I can call the java function dashboardView.displayOrHide(). I don't know how to make this happen.

I want to show or hide the datatable, maybe collapse it or not by clicking a button, and save the state of the datatable in the java bean

My version of Primefaces is 6.0.15.

My JSF/xhtml code :

```
<p:commandButton value="Show Or Hide" id="ajax" action="#{dashboardView.displayOrHide}" style="margin-right:20px;" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />

<p:dataTable id="item_#{synopticLocationBean.id}" var="synopticIdBean" value="#{synopticLocationBean.synopticIdBeans}">
   <p:column headerText="Famille">
       <h:outputText value="#{synopticIdBean.family}" />
   </p:column>

   <p:column headerText="BT">
      <h:outputText value="#{synopticIdBean.brNumber}"/>
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

My Java code, but I don't know what to do here :

```
public void buttonAction() {
   System.out.println("test ash retor ana");
}
```

For the moment I use a javascript function with a button

And hide or show my datatable with the displayTabInformation js function :

```
function displayTabInformation(id,dataTableId){

    var divDisplay = dataTableId.style.display;

    if(divDisplay === ''){
        dataTableId.style.setProperty('display', 'none');
    }else if(divDisplay === 'none'){
        dataTableId.style.setProperty('display', 'block');
    }else{
        if(divDisplay === 'visible'){
            dataTableId.style.setProperty('display', 'none');
        }else{
            if(divDisplay === 'block'){
                dataTableId.style.setProperty('display', 'none');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to make the same function with the java bean for saving which database is show or hide.

Comment: Break down your problem. How would you 'collapse' a plain html table? Do the same here... client-side it is all html, css and javascript

Comment: For the moment I use a JS method that do "dataTableId.style.setProperty('display', 'block');", or none instead block but I don't know how I can use the id of the parameter for the java method and inside the java method display or not my JSF/primefaces component.

Comment: Please add the JS example on how you do it to the question. It makes clear you at least have some basics working. And I have no clue what you mean by _"I don't know how I can use the id of the parameter for the java method and inside the java method display or not my JSF/primefaces component."_...  Always better to write 'pseudo code' then in the question to make your question more clear. Cheres

Answer (score -1):

I have added a command button that call a function from a java managed bean. I have a boolean flag that is used in the "rendered" of the datatable which is set to true or false in the showOrHideLocation function.

I don't know how to refresh my JSF page from my Java managed bean

```
<p:commandButton value="#{synopticLocationBean.name}" update="item_#{synopticLocationBean.id}" action="#{dashboardView.dashboardService.showOrHideLocation(synopticLocationBean.id)}" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" ajax="true" />

<p:dataTable id="item_#{synopticLocationBean.id}" var="synopticIdBean" value="#{synopticLocationBean.synopticIdBeans}"
    sortBy="#{synopticIdBean.longEnteredTime}" sortOrder="ascending"
    rowStyleClass="#{synopticIdBean.alarm eq true ? 'old' : null}"
    rendered="#{synopticLocationBean.collapseDataTable eq true}">

    <p:column headerText="Famille">
        <h:outputText value="#{synopticIdBean.family}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="BT">
        <h:outputText value="#{synopticIdBean.brNumber}"/>
    </p:column>
```

My Java showOrHideLocation function :

```
public void showOrHideLocation(String id) {

    SynopticLocationBean synopticLocationBean = getLocation(id);
    boolean isCollapsed = synopticLocationBean .getCollapseDataTable();
    location.setCollapseDataTable(!isCollapsed);

//TODO How can i refresh my JSF page with my java bean ?
}
```

Comment: Why not combine the two solutions? And e.g. in the on-click of the commandbutton client-side hiding and just notifying the server of the hiding? Then there is no need to update the page... And btw, you are already trying to update things since you have the `update` attribute present on the commandButton

Comment: Ok, for combining the two solutions, but how I am supposed to call a java function from managed beans in a javascript function ?

Comment: java has methods, javascript has functions. So the question in the previous comment is for me not clear. And besides that, the commandButton already calls the server and the onclick you can have on the commandButton can be used to call the client-side javascript like mentioned above, so I do not understand what you see as a problem This  (removed some code) should do it `<p:commandButton value="#{synopticLocationBean.name}"action="#{dashboardView.dashboardService.showOrHideLocation(synopticLocationBean.id)}" onclick="displayTabInformation(..., '#{synopticLocationBean.id}')"  />`

Comment: And effectively this is not an answer... The refreshing in the showOrHideLocation is irrelevant then